# Qt static library doesn't output any files after build

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I create a new project and select **Library->C++ Library**. then select **Statically Linked Library** and simply next other pages in wizard.
After this when i try to build this new project, no output files (like .a) are produced.

This is my **.pro** file content:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-11-23T03:48:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui

TARGET = ssss
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib

SOURCES += ssss.cpp

HEADERS += ssss.h
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

I am using Qt 5.4.2 and Qt Creator 3.4.1

Comment: Is there something inside `ssss.cpp`? Perhaps the archive is not created at all if it would be empty?

Comment: I thought about that and fill some blob code in my files but no chance. From voidrealms videos, he build a static library just after he create the project.

Comment: Well, it souldn't be all that hard to write a function with a single `qDebug()` statement to check.

Comment: have you tried to add QT+= core to the .pro file ? Also you have to export the definitions using Q_DECL_EXPORT. I hope it helps.

Comment: As i did some research on Libraries, it seems that Q_DECL_EXPORT used for shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the output path to a specific path use:

```
DESTDIR = /your/output/path/
```

for example if you want your output to be created in your current project directory use:

```
DESTDIR = $$PWD
```